# setBackgroundMessageHandler doesnt return anything even though notification has been sent in iOS

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using @react-native-firebase/messaging for my push notifcation but,
For some reason I am unable to get setBackgroundMessageHandler to print console.log when I'm debugging with my simulator and my real iphone even though the notification has been set in iOS. I tried to follow the tutorial for firebase cloud messaging.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I got all Background fetch, remote notification and background processing lined up. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to configure `headless`.

[headless document](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background-application-state)

- Example

```js
// index.js
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

function HeadlessCheck({ isHeadless }) {
  if (isHeadless) {
    // App has been launched in the background by iOS, ignore
    return null;
  }

  return <App />;
}

function App() {
  // Your application
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => HeadlessCheck);
```

Second, For iOS specific "data-only" messages, the message must include the appropriate APNs headers as well as the `content-available` flag in order to trigger the background handler. For example, if using the Node.js firebase-admin package to send a "data-only" message to an iOS device:

- Example

```
admin.messaging().send({
  data: {
    //some data
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        contentAvailable: true, // add this !!
      },
    },
    headers: {
      'apns-push-type': 'background',
      'apns-priority': '5',
      'apns-topic': '', // your app bundle identifier
    },
  },
  //must include token, topic, or condition
  //token: //device token
  //topic: //notification topic
  //condition: //notification condition
});
```